# Evaluate the Integral using Contour Integration (Theorem of Residues)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

$$
J(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(b x)}{\sinh(a x)} dx
$$

This integral is difficult because contour integrals normally cannot be solved with a sin(x) term in the numerator because of singularity issues between the 1st quadrant to the 2nd quadrant in the upper half circle of the contour.

I've assumed:
$$
\sin(bx)=e^{ibz}
$$

since it effectively IS the sine term in the upper half circle.

I've also used the following substitutions:
$$
x=z  ;  z=re^{i\theta}   ;  z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)
$$

From what I understand, the x range has to include all values somehow.
When I plug in the substitutions and the Euler forms of sin and sinh, the integral becomes:
$$
2\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{e^{ibx}}{e^{ax}-e^{ax}}dx
$$

Have I screwed up the subs?  Did I reduce incorrectly?  Not sure what to go from here. If anyone could help shed some light it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well.. your integral has 0 denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note first that the integrand is even and can be extended to the entire real line.  Consider

$$f(z) = \frac{e^{i b z}}{\sinh{a z}}$$

$b>0$, in the upper half complex plane.  Then

$$\oint_C dz \: \frac{e^{i b z}}{\sinh{a z}}$$

is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues within $C$, which we'll take to be a semicircle of large radius in the upper half plane indented at the origin to include the pole at $z=0$.  The integral about the semicircular arc goes to zero as this radius goes to infinity because of Jordan's Lemma.  Then the integral of $f$ along the real line is the sum of the residues within $C$.

$\sinh{a z}$ has poles at $z=i n \pi/a$, $n \ge 0$.    The residue term here is a little tricky, but may be shown to be equal to

$$\text{Res}_{z=i n \pi/a} f(z) = \frac{(-1)^n}{a} e^{-n \pi b/a}$$

The integral along the real line is then the sum of all the residues within $C$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: \frac{e^{i b x}}{\sinh{a x}} =\frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-n \pi b/a} = \frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \frac{1}{1+e^{-\pi b/a}}$$

For the case $b<0$, we use a contour in the lower half plane but indented to *exclude* the pole at $z=0$ (which was already included before); the result is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: \frac{e^{-i b x}}{\sinh{a x}} =\frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-n \pi b/a} = -\frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \frac{1}{1+e^{\pi b/a}}$$

Then we take $1/2$ the sum to get the integral over the positive reals:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} dx \: \frac{\sin{b x}}{\sinh{a x}} = \frac{\pi}{2 a} \tanh{\left(\pi \frac{b}{2 a}\right)}$$

Comment: Why do you neglect 0? You changed the function to exponential. It is not sin function any more.

Comment: You are calculating the integral of $\frac{e^{ibx}}{\sinh ax}$, and that function clearly has a singularity at 0, and your contour has the point.

Comment: If you want to exclude 0, then you should have started from calculating the integral of $\frac{\sin bz}{\sinh az}$.

Comment: I just realized a mistake there - see edit in 2 min.

Comment: If so, the answer will match with mine. My answer got down-voted unfairly.

Comment: I have a different contour. In my contour, I have only two poles to consider.

Comment: I see, and I upvoted you back.  But I did not downvote you.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it. I think the downvote is from someone else, anyway thanks for getting it back to me. I don't really care about my points, but I can't stand getting unfair downvote.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  I have had this happen to me several times in the past, and it certainly can be frustrating.

Comment: Even if it leads to the same answer, I find it a bit strange to not indent either contour at the origin and pretend that the pole at the origin is inside of the upper contour. Did you just do that for expediency?

Comment: Yes; I'll edit to make clear.

Comment: The summation indices start from $0$ or $1$? Either way, should start from the same places.

Comment: Note I indented the contour, so the upper includes the $z=0$, while the lower excludes.  So, the summations are OK.

Comment: Also, if you make an indent on your contour, it should contribute half of residue.

Comment: I see. I did not know you edited it.

Comment: Yes, the contour excludes the pole.  I hate when poles are on contours.  Blech.

Comment: Even though you indented your contour, it will still contribute the half of residue. eIn this case, they will end up cancelling each other, so the answer will be the same.

Comment: Each of the integrals would have to contain the term coming from half of residue at 0.

Comment: Hi could you simplify how $-\frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \frac{1}{1+e^{\pi b/a}} = \frac{\pi}{2a}\tanh (\pi n/2a)$ ??

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: not what I say; read the solution again.  One is related to the imaginary part of the other.

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: that's right.

Comment: the index is starting from 1, shouldn't it be like this 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \: \frac{e^{-i b x}}{\sinh{a x}} =\frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-n \pi b/a} = -\frac{i 2 \pi}{a} \frac{e^{\pi b/a}}{1+e^{\pi b/a}}$$

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: no, because the ratio of the geometric sum is $e^{-\pi b/a}$.

Comment: all right ... i see thanks for taking your time to explain me.
since i have already used my vote here, i'll give +1 on your any other answer.

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: while I appreciate the sentiment, please do not upvote me in return for a favor or service I provide you.  Upvote the responses you like, that's good, but it is not to be seen as a payment-in-kind, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ . Since $\cos$ part will disappear, 
Rewrite the integrand as
$$
\frac{e^{ibx}}{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}=\frac{\exp\{(a+ib)x\}}{\exp(2ax)-1}
$$

Take the contour $[-R,R]$, $[R,R+\frac{i\pi}{a}]$, $[R+\frac{i\pi}{a},-R+\frac{i\pi}{a}]$, $[-R+\frac{i\pi}{a}, -R]$. (We will take $R\rightarrow\infty$).

However the integrand has singularities at $x=0$ and $x=\frac{i\pi}{a}$, so detour those points by taking upper half circle of small radius $\epsilon$ at $x=0$, and lower half circle of small radius $\epsilon$ at $x=\frac{i\pi}{a}$. Then the contour does not have singularities inside. (We will take $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$).

Note that the integrals on the vertical sides and the small part of the horizontal lines around $0$ and $\frac{i\pi}{a}$  will vanish with $R\rightarrow\infty$ and $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Denote the integral by $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ibx}}{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}dx$. Then by Residue Theorem, we have
$$
I-I\exp\{(a+ib)\frac{i\pi}{a}\}-\frac{1}{2}2\pi i \frac{1}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}2\pi i\frac{1}{2a}\exp\{(a+ib)\frac{i\pi}{a}\}=0
$$
We solve this for $I$, it now follows that 
$$
J(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(b x)}{\sinh(a x)} dx=-iI=\frac{\pi}{2a}\frac{1-\exp(-\frac{b}{a}\pi)}{1+\exp(-\frac{b}{a}\pi)}
$$
and this RHS is the integral that we wanted in the beginning.

Comment: $x=0$ is obtained when $n=0$ for $\frac{in\pi}{a}$.

Comment: What's up with the factor of $i$?  The integral is real.

Comment: I integrated $\frac{e^{ibx}}{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}$. It has $i$ on $\sin$ part.

Comment: I guess you need to make clear what your $I$ is.  If you are solving for $I$, don't you want that $I$ to be the integral of interest?  Otherwise, it's kind of confusing.

Comment: Okay, edited.!!

Comment: OK, that's better.  Not to be a hardass, but now you haven't answered the OP's question.  You should really finish this off: what is the OP's integral in terms of $I$?

Comment: Yes. I admit that mine was confusing with $i$'s. Changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\on{J}\pars{a,b} & \equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty }{\sin\pars{bx} \over \sinh\pars{ax}}\,\dd x} =
\on{sgn}\pars{a}\int_{0}^{\infty }{\sin\pars{bx} \over \sinh\pars{\verts{a}x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x\ =\ t/\pars{2\verts{a}}}{=}\,\,\,
\left.{1 \over 2a}\int_{0}^{\infty }{\sin\pars{\beta t/2} \over \sinh\pars{t/2}}\,\dd t
\,\right\vert_{\,\ds{\beta\ \equiv\ b/\verts{a}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\ic \over 2a}\int_{0}^{\infty }
{\expo{-\pars{1 - \beta\,\ic}t/2}\,\,\, -\,
\expo{-\pars{1 + \beta\,\ic}t/2} \over 1 - \expo{-t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\ic \over 2a}\left[%
\int_{0}^{\infty }
{1 - \expo{-\pars{1 + \beta\,\ic}t/2} \over 1 - \expo{-t}}
\,\dd t\right.
\\[2mm] & \phantom{-\,{\ic \over 2a}\,\,\,\,\,}\left.
-\int_{0}^{\infty }
{1 - \expo{-\pars{1 - \beta\,\ic}t/2} \over 1 - \expo{-t}}
\,\dd t\right]\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\ic \over 2a}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} + {\beta\,\ic \over 2}} -
\Psi\pars{{1 \over 2} - {\beta\,\ic \over 2}}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\ic \over 2a}\braces{%
\pi\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{%
{1 \over 2} - {\beta\,\ic \over 2}}}} =
-\,{\pi\ic \over 2a}\tan\pars{\beta\,\ic \over 2}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{\pi \over 2a}\tanh\pars{b \over 2\verts{a}}} \\ &
\end{align}

- $\ds{\Psi}$: *Digamma Function*.
- (\ref{2}): [See $\ds{\color{black}{\bf 6.3.22}}$ in A & S Table](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).
- (\ref{3}): *Euler Reflection Formula*. [See $\ds{\color{black}{\bf 6.3.7}}$ in A & S Table](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).